# php to open PDF from network folder

Tags: php

Im totally new to PHP and Iv been given the task to create a web page where the user enters a number and the corresponding pdf opens in a new tab.
All our pdf’s are of drawings and stored under their drawing number and stored on a local server.
At the moment I can open pdf’s but only if there stored on my PC, if I try to access the server folder it says the file cant be found.
at the moment I just trying to open a PDF from the server location.

```
<?php 
set_include_path(".;I:\Soildedge\User\drawings\pdf");
$filename = "test.pdf";
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
readfile($filename);
?>
```

thanks

Comment: `include_path` only affects the paths searched by `include` and `require`, not by regular filesystem functions, like `readfile`. Give readfile the full absolute path to the file you want to read.

Comment: If I give the full path in readfile:
    [$filename = "E:\Soildedge \pdf/test.pdf";
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    readfile($filename);]

E:\ is a network drive and it says “the format of the source is not PDF” (which it also says if it can’t find the file)
If I then recreate the file structure on my PC as below it works

    '$filename = "C:\Soildedge\pdf/test.pdf";
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    readfile($filename);'

How do I get to view files stored on the network?

Comment: well thats a mess lol